# C# (Array of object) object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I am getting the object reference error in this line:
emp[count].emp_id = int.Parse(parts[0]);

in this code

### this program to read from file and store in array of object

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class employees
    {
        public int emp_id;
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public double balance;
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult result = file.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) return;

        string fileName = file.FileName;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        int emp_count = lines.Count<string>();
        employees[] emp = new employees[emp_count];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] parts = new string[4];
            parts = line.Split(',');
            **emp[count].emp_id = int.Parse(parts[0]);**
            emp[count].firstName = parts[1];
            emp[count].lastName = parts[2];
            emp[count].balance = double.Parse(parts[3]);
            count++;
            txtGet.Text += emp[count].emp_id + " " + emp[count].firstName + " " + emp[count].lastName + " " + emp[count].balance + " \n ";

        }
```

Comment: Sorry what about read data in one file and store it in array of object  Then write this data in new file.
               string path="D:\\new.txt";
               StreamWriter writer;
               writer = File.CreateText(path);
              string record = " ";
              for (int i = 0; i <emp_count; i++)
            {
                record+= emp[0].emp_id + "," +
                        emp[1].firstName + "," +
                        emp[2].lastName + "," +
                        emp[3].balance + "\n";
            }
            writer.WriteLine(record);
            writer.Close();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to initialise `emp[count]` to something.

You can do this by adding the following:

```
foreach (string line in lines) 
{ 
    emp[count] = new employees();
    string[] parts = new string[4]; 
    //....
}
```

When you call `employees[] emp = new employees[emp_count];` you initilise `emp` to an array of `employees` with the length of `emp_count`.

```
emp[0] = null;
emp[1] = null;
//etc.
```

Each element inside `emp` also needs to be instantiated before you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

`emp[0]` has not been initialized. Class `employees` is a nullable type, which means arrays made of it are initialized to nulls. Initialize `emp[count]` to `new employees`.

BTW, "`employees`" is a strange name for a class that holds a single employee. I think it should be called `Employee`, then it makes sens to declare your array like this:

```
 `Employee[] employees = new Employee[emp_count];`
```