# How to create array of 100 new objects?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying something like that:

```
class point
{
public int x;
public int y;
}

point[] array = new point[100];
array[0].x = 5;
```

and here's the error:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (@ the last line)**

whats wrong? :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# (Array of object) object reference not set to an instance of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832765/c-sharp-array-of-object-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) - see my answer.

Comment: You may want to use a struct (value type) instead of class (references). Other than that, instanciate the class point in a loop using the constructor : array[i] = new point()

Comment: You never created `array[0]`, so how can you set its value to `5`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It only creates the array, but all elements are initialized with null.
You need a loop or something similar to create instances of your class.
(foreach loops dont work in this case)
Example:

```
point[] array = new point[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    array[i] = new point();
}

array[0].x = 5;
```

Comment: To add to @Skalli's answer here, if your `Point` were a struct instead of a class (as the Point type is in the BCL), then you wouldn't need to worry about this.  Class's need to be "new'd" when used in arrays, structs don't.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: Care to explain what you don't like about the question and how I can improve it?

Comment: That was not me, but your example is incorrect. One cannot assign foreach iteration variable. There have to be another loop type:

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] = new point();

Answer (score 7):

When you do

```
point[] array = new point[100];
```

you create an array, not 100 objects. Elements of the array are null. At that point you have to create each element:

```
array[0] = new point();
array[0].x = 5;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change `class point` to `struct point` in that case `new point[500]` will create an array of points initialized to `0,0` (rather than array of null's).

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers explain, you need to initialize the objects at each array location. You can use a method such as the following to create pre-initialized arrays

```
T[] CreateInitializedArray<T>(int size) where T : new()
{
    var arr = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = new T();
    return arr;
}
```

If your class doesn't have a parameterless constructor you could use something like:

```
T[] CreateInitializedArray<T>(int size, Func<T> factory)
{
    var arr = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = factory();
    return arr;
}
```

LINQ versions for both methods are trivial, but slightly less efficient I believe

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] asd = new int[99];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    asd[i] = i;
```

Something like that?

Comment: If you are going to use an index, you better use `for (int i=0; i < asd.Length; ++i)`We don't want to risk an IndexOutOfRangeException. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes LINQ comes in handy. It may provide some extra readability and reduce boilerplate and repetition. The downside is that extra allocations are required: enumerators are created and ToArray does not know the array size beforehand, so it might need to reallocate the internal buffer several times. **Use only in code whose maintainability is much more critical than its performance.**

```
using System.Linq;

const int pointsCount = 100;
point[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, pointsCount)
    .Select(_ => new point())
    .ToArray()
```