# Joining of tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    A.AREA_CODE, 
    A.OUTLET_NAME, 
    SUM (C.amount) as E_SALES,
    SUM (B.amount) as NETSALES 
FROM
    M_OUTLET A,
    E_SALES_DETAIL C, 
    T_SALES_DETAIL B
WHERE
    A.OUTLET_no = B.OUTLET_NO
AND A.OUTLET_NO = C.OUTLET_NO
AND A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%head%office%'
AND A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%prod%'
AND A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%stor%'
AND MONTH (B.SYSTEM_DATE) = MONTH ( '" & dtpMonthNetsales.Text & "')
AND YEAR (B.SYSTEM_DATE ) = YEAR ('" & dtpMonthNetsales.Text & "')
AND B.VOID = 'N' AND C.VOID = 'N'
GROUP BY A.AREA_CODE , A.OUTLET_NAME
ORDER BY A.AREA_CODE
```

But when I run my program it takes so long to show the output and it says;

> Timeout expired. The time period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding.

I also tried to run my code in MS SQL Server 2008 and it takes 1 minute and 42 seconds to show the output.

My classmate says that I must try to use derived tables but I don't know how to do that.
I searched at the internet but I can't see the right explanation for me.

The output must be like this:

```
AREA_CODE      OUTLET_NAME          E_SALES         NETSALES
1          MAKATI BU CAFE 2      582458.46       582458.46
2          MAKATI BU CART        365825.45        365825.45
```

Comment: What indexes have you got on the tables?  At the very least each table should have an index on OUTLET_NO.  Also you seem to implying that youare creating SQL inline in code rather than calling a stored procedure.  There are all sorts of performance issues and security issues by creating dynamic SQL in code.

Comment: What do you mean by that Sir? OUTLET_NO as OUTLET?

Comment: You have in your where statement. A.OUTLET_no = B.OUTLET_NO and A.OUTLET_NO = C.OUTLET_NO. If there is no index on these fields then the join will be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:

 SELECT A.AREA_CODE, 
        A.OUTLET_NAME, 
        SUM (C.amount) as E_SALES,
        SUM (B.amount) as NETSALES 
   FROM M_OUTLET A
        INNER JOIN E_SALES_DETAIL C ON A.OUTLET_NO = C.OUTLET_NO
        INNER JOIN T_SALES_DETAIL B ON A.OUTLET_no = B.OUTLET_NO 
  WHERE B.VOID = 'N' 
    AND C.VOID = 'N'
    AND MONTH(B.SYSTEM_DATE) = MONTH('" & dtpMonthNetsales.Text & "')
    AND YEAR(B.SYSTEM_DATE) = YEAR('" & dtpMonthNetsales.Text & "')
    AND A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%head%office%'
    AND A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%prod%'
    AND A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC not like '%stor%'
  GROUP BY A.AREA_CODE, A.OUTLET_NAME
  ORDER BY A.AREA_CODE
```

If possible try not to use LIKE operator

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try your code but it gives me message like this: The multi-part identifier “A.OUTLET_NO” could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier “A.OUTLET_TYPE_DESC” could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier “A.AREA_CODE” could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier “A.OUTLET_NAME” could not be bound.

Comment: Sorry if I have so many questions. I am just new to visual studio 2010 your new code shows the message: "object reference  not set to an instance of an object". Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: This seems to be a .net issue. Check the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean