# Object returning null after creating object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm playing around with ASP.net, using a code first approach to create and use a database.

Using the code below I get an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' Object reference not set to an instance of an object (see code for specific line).

When I step through the application, the variable in question, 'p' has a value of {Code_first_database.Models.Product}, not null.

I've looked at [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it%22What%20is%20a%20NullReferenceException%20and%20how%20do%20I%20fix%20it?%22) and [What does “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean) but I still cant seem to see the problem.

Any help much appreciated.

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace Code_first_database.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Models.Product p = new Models.Product("Soft331", "Book");
            using (var db = new Models.ProductDB())
            {
                db.products.Add(p); // **EXCEPTION THROWN HERE**
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "The number of products so far is " +
                    db.products.Count().ToString();
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
namespace Code_first_database.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Product_Code { get; set; }
        public string Product_Name { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }

        public Product(string p_code, string p_name)
        {
            Product_Code = p_code;
            Product_Name = p_name;
        }
    }
}
```

**ProductDB.cs**

```
namespace Code_first_database.Models
{
    public class ProductDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> products;

        public ProductDB() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks
Tony

Comment: Does your `db` variable actually have a non-null `products` property?

Comment: I dont think so, and I haven't added one. How would I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you need to use properties instead of variables in Entity Framework. Change

```
public DbSet<Product> products;
```

to

```
public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }
```

Comment: I've added the code for ProductDB.cs to the question. Ive just tried to add 'products = new DbSet<Product>();' into the constructor but it's inaccessible due to it's protection level.

Comment: @tonyedwardspz I don't think you need to initialize it, try changing variable to property first

Comment: Fantastic. The getter and setter sorted it. Thanks for the help :)