# FileUpload gives 'System.NullReferenceException' on post to method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, file-upload

**EDIT: The problem happened to be the jQuery-Mobile library that removed my file when i was doing a postback. I still have no idea why, but I'm trying to make a custom jQuery-Mobile library now to see what causes my problem.**

I'm trying to make a form where people can upload their resumé and send it to me, but I'm having some issues with it. I'm sending the form to the backend, to the method **SendJobMail** and everything gets read out, except for the content from the **FileUpload**.

I tried adding breakpoints and it'll break at this line:

```
string attachmentFilename = Path.GetFileName(CVUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=PublicSite_ASP
  StackTrace:
       at PublicSite_ASP.TestPage.SendJobMail() in c:\Users\joris.decraecker\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Public Website-Mobile\PublicSite_ASP\default.aspx.cs:line 225
       at PublicSite_ASP.TestPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\joris.decraecker\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Public Website-Mobile\PublicSite_ASP\default.aspx.cs:line 31
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

I also tried changing the FileUpload but to this, but that didn't work either:

```
<label>Selecteer uw CV</label>
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="CVUpload" />
```

.

**Here is my current code:**

HTML:

```
<form runat="server" id="frmApplication" name="frmApplication" role="form" action="default.aspx/SendJobMail" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="vacancyId" Value="" />
        <div class="col-sm-6 column">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 column form-column">
                            <label for="txtNameJob" class="sr-only">Voornaam</label>
                            <input runat="server" id="txtNameJob" name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Voornaam" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 column form-column">
                            <label for="txtSurnameJob" class="sr-only">Achternaam</label>
                            <input runat="server" id="txtSurnameJob" name="lastName" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Achternaam" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-12 column form-column">
                            <label for="txtEmailJob" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                            <input runat="server" id="txtEmailJob" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-12 column form-column">
                            <label for="txtTel" class="sr-only">Telefoon</label>
                            <input runat="server" id="txtTel" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 column">
            <label for="txtMessageJob" class="sr-only">Motivatie</label>
            <textarea runat="server" id="txtMessageJob" name="motivation" class="form-control input-lg" rows="7" placeholder="Motivatie"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-6 column">
                    <div class="input-group form-column"> 
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-file">
                                Bladeren...
                                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="CVUpload" />
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <input runat="server" type="text" id="fileTextField" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Selecteer uw CV" readonly="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 column">
                    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Solliciteren" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  pull-right" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void SendJobMail()
        {
            var client = new MailerServiceReference.IemailClient();
            bool succeeded = false;

            string recipient = "jobs@domain.eu";
            string firstName = txtNameJob.Value;
            string lastName = txtSurnameJob.Value;
            string telNr = txtTel.Value;
            string motivation = txtMessageJob.Value;
            string sender = "info@domain.eu";  

            int vacId = Int32.Parse(vacancyId.Value);
            string vacTitle = _vacancies.Find(vac => vac.Id == vacId).Title;
            string subject = string.Format("Application from {0} {1} for {2}", firstName, lastName, vacTitle);

            motivation += string.Format("\n\n{0}{1}\n{2}\n{3}", firstName, lastName, txtEmailJob.Value, telNr);

            //set up and add an attachment
            string attachmentFilename = Path.GetFileName(CVUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(CVUpload.FileContent, attachmentFilename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet); //can interpret PDF and richtextdocument

            ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition; //disposition necessary for some mailing applications
            disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(attachmentFilename);
            disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(attachmentFilename);
            disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(attachmentFilename);
            disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachmentFilename);
            disposition.Size = CVUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;

            try
            {
                client.Open();
                succeeded = client.SendEmail("PublicSite", sender, "info@domain.eu", subject, motivation);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("lalala " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Comment: Well, I know what the error message means, but I don't understand why the FileUpload is empty and the rest of the input hás a content.

Comment: When do you call the function: SendJobMail() ? is it called when submit is clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to save the file before using it..

```
if (CVUpload.HasFile)
{
    var savePath = @"c:\temp\uploads\" + CVUpload.FileName;
    CVUpload.SaveAs(savePath);
    DisplayFileContents(CVUpload.PostedFile);
}
```

[More Info: FileUpload - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It'll just skip the if statement because the CVUpload actually has no file. I think the file gets lost during the postback or something..

Comment: Yes, everything except the FileUpload content.
http://oi62.tinypic.com/ruwk87.jpg

Comment: I found where the problem is, but not the way to solve it.. I removed the jQuery-Mobile script and now it seems to be working, but why?