# Add Service Failed error while adding web service reference to WPF project

Tags: web-services

I have created a web service. I'm trying to add this web service(.asmx) refrence to my WPF application. During adding service reference, I get this below error (Visual studio dialog box).

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have never encountered this error before. Please suggest solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Comment: No. There's no duplicate. It isn't allowing me to add service reference