# cmd.ExecuteScalar() Object reference not set to an instance of an object vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this code. I've tried to run this code with SQL (PHP myadmin) and I can receive my data but this code doesn't not work.

```vb
For i = 0 To arr_pdetail.Length
    Dim cmdText = "Select price from tb_pdetail where category = @car"
    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cat", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = arr_pdetail(i)
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        If result Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("No category found")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Found category with price " & result.ToString())
        End If
    End Using
    'sum_cost = sum_cost + price
Next
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Comment: Is `conn` initialized?

Comment: `For i = 0 To arr_pdetail.Length` should be `For i = 0 To (arr_pdetail.Length - 1)`. Still a dupe though.

Comment: @GSerg it's connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) could return null (Nothing in VB) if there is no `category` matching your condition, you should add some defensive action against the result of `ExecuteScalar`

```
Dim cmdText = "Select price from tb_pdetail where category = @cat"
Using conn = new MySqlConnection(...........)
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cat", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  arr_pdetail(i)
    Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    if result Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("No category found")
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Found the category with price " & result.ToString())
    End If
End Using
```

In this reworking of your code, the return of `ExecuteScalar` is checked against `Nothing` before trying to use it. If the result is Nothing this could only mean that your table doesn't contain a row with the Category column having the requested value.

Notice also that I have used a parameterized query instead of a string concatenation to avoid possible [Sql Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and parsing problems and finally I have put the disposable objects like the `MySqlCommand` and the `MySqlConnection` inside a [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to avoid memory leaks and unnecessary usage of costly resources.

Comment: The error is still on the cmd.ExecuteScalar line? Are you sure that you write exactly as above? Do not define the _Dim result as String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()_

Comment: it's my fault. i for got open mysqlconnection