# How to get text from a "Edittext"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, argumentnullexception

I am trying to get text from an `EditText` in android but I have an Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried to look for a solution online, but I  didn't find any.
I just need to get the text from the `EditText` and pass it to a string

My code:

```
EditText edip = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
EditText edport = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);

string customip = edip.Text;
string customport = edport.Text;
```

Comment: Are you sure that editText1 and editText2 are in your view?  Which stage of the app lifecycle is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
EditText edip = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
```

...
should work fine.

Comment: Can you a bit more details? How this code snippet solves the problem?