# Query WHERE IN clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, c#-4.0, oledbdataadapter

In a SQL query we are using `WHERE IN` clause to filter the data. When I am passing 35000 fields in `WHERE IN` clause, The `ExecuteNonQuery` throws

> Object reference not set to an instance exception

I have used try catch in where the ExecuteNonQuery excuted, but the exception not catched current method, it catched in parent method (button click)

If I reduced the count from 35000 to 25000 the SQL query works fine. Please help.

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRY WHERE CountryID in ('1','2',......'35000')
```

I have tried to use Temp Table in SQL also, Same error happened.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp)IS NOT NULL DROP #TEMP 
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
( CountryID int NULL)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('1')
.
.
.
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('10')

SELECT * FROM COUNTRY WHERE CountryID IN(SELECT CountryID from #temp)
```

The object null reference error is not the problem, How can i overcome the Where In clause issue in sql query. What would the possible resolution to avoid the Where in clause in sql query.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Comment: Show your code behind

Comment: If CountryID are integers why do you put them inside your IN as strings?

Comment: OT, there are only about 200 countries in the whole world...

Comment: @Steve Can we avoid the exception when we use the CountryID as integer in WHERE IN?

Comment: 35000 items in a IN are a lot of data. Anyway, if the field is integer then passing string will be only a possible source of troubles.  Just try it

Comment: @jarlh: i put countryID is just for example.. :) but in project different key names we are using.

Comment: @jarlh : This is not a duplicate question right?

Comment: You have still not told us which dbms you're using.

Comment: @jarlh from his temp table code I *assume* it´s SQL Server. Anyway Cegone should clarify this and also tell us which version of dbms he´s using.

Comment: @jarlh : We are using RDMS, SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Steve : Thanks for you tip, It's working when i pass the ConutryID's as integer without single quote. I could fetch more than 35000 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use join instead, this should work

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRY c INNER JOIN #temp t on c.CountryId=t.CountryId
```

Comment: It it worked for you, please mark the answer correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use between?

`SELECT * FROM COUNTRY WHERE CountryID between 1 and 10`

Comment: Perhaps there are gaps?

Comment: @jarlh I don't know how he gets what ID to select but you can use `OR`, `SELECT * FROM COUNTRY WHERE CountryID between 1 and 4 or CountryID between 8 and 10`

Comment: @Cegone Ah.. ok, sorry. Your first example made me think it's just 1-35000