# Writing a passed Array via session into Label isn't working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to take an array of string (Filled from a listbox on a previous page and passed via Session) and display it in a label,**this is how i got the array:**

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckOut.Click
    Dim x = ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices.Count
    Dim ListPNames(x) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    For Each item As String In ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices
        ListPNames(i) = (ListBox1.SelectedItem).ToString
        i = i + 1

    Next


    Session("SlctdPhones") = ListPNames(x)

    Response.Redirect("CheckOut.aspx")


End Sub
```

**And this is how i am trying to display it :**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim SlctdPhones() As String = CType(Session.Item("SlctdPhones"), Array)
    Dim i As Integer

    Label3.Text = ""

    For i = 0 To SlctdPhones.Length - 1

    Label3.Text += SlctdPhones(i).ToString() + Environment.NewLine
    Next


End Sub
```

It is giving me an error :**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** when it reaches the SlctdPhones.Length - 1 Line!!
i don't know how i can fix it ,also is my array code correct(Is everything being stored correctly in it?)

Comment: Probably related: [What does “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Comment: but the array is already declared and took the values from the previous page,why am i still getting the error?! that's what i don't understand

Comment: If you can't tell for yourself via the debugger if the array has the correct data, you need to go back to the fundamentals here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the `For` loop like this:

```
For Each item In ...
```

But then never use the `item` variable in the body of the loop. Instead, you keep using the same `SelectedItem` property. You want to change that whole method to look like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckOut.Click
    Dim PNames As New List(Of String)()
    For Each index As Integer In ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices
        PNames.Add(ListBox1.Items(index).Value)
    Next
    Session("SlctdPhones") = PNames

    Response.Redirect("CheckOut.aspx")
End Sub
```

With that fixed, the Page_Load can do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim SlctdPhones As List(Of String) = TryCast(Session.Item("SlctdPhones"), List(Of String))

    If SlctdPhones Is Nothing OrElse SlctdPhones.Length = 0 Then
        'Something went wrong here!
        Return
    End If

    Label3.Text = String.Join("<br/>", SlctdPhones.ToArray())
End Sub
```

But I'd really love to see you use a data control rather than stuffing `<br/>`s into a label. Here's markup for a ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
    <ul>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
    </ul>                
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <li><%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <p>Nothing here.</p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And then Page_Load is even simpler:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ListView1.DataSource =  Session.Item("SlctdPhones")
    ListView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried both ,and ended up using the list view because it is much better and cleaner to use.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On display page, use Literal instead of Label

```
Dim SlctdPhones() As String = CType(Session.Item("SlctdPhones"), Array)
Dim result as String = string.Join("<br>", SlctdPhones) 'Instead of <br> try Environment.NewLine as well 
YourLitetal = result
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another option could be,, you just create a delimited (by line-break) string at first page (rather array), pass it to next page, and display with using Literal.

YourLiteral = Session("DelimitedSelectedItem").ToString()

Thanks