# DataGrid SelectedItems for each loop exception

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

As I'm scrolling through the datagrid and selecting items on and off the visible screen, it throws the following exception.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

`Dim sn as string` is the culprit...

```
For Each item In asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedItems
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
       Dim snIndex As Integer = asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.LastOrDefault(Function(c) c.Header = "serial num"))
       Dim sn As String = DirectCast(asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedCells(snIndex).Column.GetCellContent(item), TextBlock).Text
       variables.selectedAssets.Add(sn)
    End If
Next
```

When `EnableRowVirtualization="True"` is true, I get the error. I'm assuming this is because once I scroll off the screen, while having rows selected, those rows no longer exist.

How do I avoid this, without turning off virtualization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Comment: That's funny, if I turn off EnableRowVirtualization it works fine, but with it on, it doesn't. I know what the error means, but don't understand why it happens with row virtualization on, or a hint at fixing it.

Comment: My bet is that with virtualization on, some of the objects you're trying to interact with don't actually exist sometimes. In WPF, it's never a good idea to interact directly with any of the cell or row objects. If you only interact with the stuff in `m_dt.DefaultView` instead, and let the grid worry about displaying it, you should be fine.

Comment: THAT was helpful, i'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Well, don't call it helpful until it helps.

Comment: Bah, still not able to figure it out. I did reformat my question, so it actually makes sense now.. so hopefully I can figure it out.

Comment: The only way you're going to avoid this without turning off virtualization is by interacting with the data model that's being displayed in the grid. You can get row and column numbers that are selected; that should be enough to work with, I would think. What did you try that didn't work with that?

Comment: I'm VERY new to WPF, so i'm trying to get winforms out of my mind, as now it's causing problems. I can get the value of a certain row, column of the datatable, but i'm having issues figuring out how to get the selected grid row to a value.. not sure if i'm even explaining that properly.

Comment: What type of thing is the grid data stored in? Is it a DataTable?

Comment: Datatable, correct. I will always know the index of the column i'm looking for usinng Dim snIndex = asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c.Header = "serial num"))

Comment: Ohh, wait a minute, I'm an idiot: `asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedItems` should be a collection of `DataRowView`. That's got a Row property whcih has an ItemArray property -- just cast. I'll do up a quick answer, but I don't know VB so it'll be a syntactical nightmare, I hope you can translate it into something the compiler doesn't laugh at.

Comment: I kind of know c#, I shouldn't have a problem converting it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the final version, with OP's corrections of my strange attempts at VB syntax:

```
Dim snIndex As Integer = asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.LastOrDefault(Function(c) c.Header = "serial num"))

'loop through all selected datagrid rows.
For Each item In asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedItems
    'check to see if item has a NULL value, it shouldn't be though.
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
        'directcast item (selected item) to a datarowview.
        Dim drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(item, DataRowView)
        'declare serial number to a string.
        Dim sn As String = drv.Row(snIndex)
        'add all serial numbers to selected asset list (so we can get a list of all the selected sn's).
        variables.selectedAssets.Add(sn)
    End If
Next
```

I think you were getting the null reference exception because you were trying to cast some part of selected item to a `TextBlock`, but there's nothing in there that's castable to that.

In WPF, `SelectedItems` means the data items that are being displayed in the UI, not the actual UI stuff. It's a subset of the whole collection items that you gave to `ItemsSource` -- whatever those are, that's what it's "selecting" when the user clicks on the grid. I had to populate my `DataGrid` like so:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

`DefaultView` returns a `DataView` which implements `IEnumerable`. Enumerate it, and it gives you `DataRowView` instances. And those are what the `DataGrid` gives you back in `SelectedItems`.

But I know just about zero about `DataTable`. If you did it some other way, if there *is* some other way, you may get something else back. So put a breakpoint in that loop and examine `item`; see what type it is. It's going to be something that represents one of your data rows, or I'll eat my hat(1).

(1) That's an *exclusive* OR.

Comment: Had to change a few things to get it to work, I'm assuming it's from the converter.... either way, this was amazing, and it works! Thanks for helping me understand. I cannot believe how easy that was :(

Comment: Once you learn WPF, it makes things very easy. Not easy to learn though. What did you change? It'd be a better if could include the working version

Comment: I've edited my question with the answer, as it was too long to post in a comment. As soon as you fix yours, I will remove it.