# Converted JSON to classes, how to set values

Tags: c#, json

I have pasted JSON in to my C# console application, so it produces classes like so :

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Id id { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
}

public class Identifier
{
    public Id1 id { get; set; }
    public Type type { get; set; }
}

public class Id1
{
    public string IdentifierString { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string IdentifierType { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to set the values of `identifierString` and `identifierType` like so :

```
var node = new Rootobject();
 node.id.Identifier.id.IdentifierString = "testId";
 node.id.Identifier.type.IdentifierType = "idType";
```

However, I get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

Comment: You need create other objects too: `node.Id = new Id();`

Comment: The `Id` class is non-static. So, you need to create an object of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON String To C# Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object)

Comment: It's better to use a serilaizer for this kind of thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write:

```
 var node = new Rootobject();
 node.id = new Id();
 node.id.Identifier = new Identifier();
 node.id.Identifier.id = new Id1();
 node.id.Identifier.type = new Type();
 node.id.Identifier.id.IdentifierString = "testId";
 node.id.Identifier.type.IdentifierType = "idType";
```

or even better:

```
var node = new Rootobject
{
  id = new Id
  {
    Identifier = new Identifier
    {
      id = new Id1 { IdentifierString = "id" },
      type = new Type { IdentifierType = "type" },
    }
  }
};
```

You are missing creation of objects, they are nulls

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) I edited the creation to create the correct objects :)

Answer (score 1):

Or version which compile :)

```
var node = new RootObject
{
    id = new Id
    { 
        Identifier = new Identifier
        {
            id = new Id1 { IdentifierString = "id" },
            type = new Type { IdentifierType = "type" },
        }
    }
};
```