# How to properly use GetMethod from inside a namespace?

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, system.reflection, methodinfo

For example, we have the following code, given by Microsoft

```
public class MagicClass
{
    private int magicBaseValue;

    public MagicClass()
    {
        magicBaseValue = 9;
    }

    public int ItsMagic(int preMagic)
    {
        return preMagic * magicBaseValue;
    }
}

public class TestMethodInfo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get the constructor and create an instance of MagicClass

        Type magicType = Type.GetType("MagicClass");
        ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[]{});

        // Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of 100

        MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");
        object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{100});

        Console.WriteLine("MethodInfo.Invoke() Example\n");
        Console.WriteLine("MagicClass.ItsMagic() returned: {0}", magicValue);
    }
}

// The example program gives the following output:
//
// MethodInfo.Invoke() Example
//
// MagicClass.ItsMagic() returned: 900
```

`MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");`
is where the program would break, if we had enclosed this whole snippet of code in any namespace of our choosing.

The exception it throws is the following:
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean

Comment: If you copy the above could it would work flawlessly, but if you add a namespace to it - it throws the exception. How do we address that?

Comment: try changing to "<namespace>.MagicClass"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetType_System_String_):

> `typeName`
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See `AssemblyQualifiedName`. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

So you have to *at least* specify the namespace when `MagicClass` is enclosed in a namespace:

```
Type magicType = Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.MagicClass");
```

otherwise it will return `null`.

Comment: I tried that and it throws the same error at ```object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[] { 100 });```

Answer (score 0):

Get the namespace dynamically if it's in the same namespace.

```
        string ns = typeof(TestMethodInfo).Namespace;
        Type magicType = Type.GetType(ns + ".MagicClass");
```