# How to Bring Child's Name to List?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwS9R.png)I intend to return the name of the child with the vaccines already administered.
what happens is that it does not return anything to me, since if I call the Id it returns the Id of the Child

Model VacinacaoIndexData

```
      using GestCentros.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GestCentros.ViewModels
{
    public class VacinacaoIndexData
    {
       public IEnumerable<Vacinacao> Vacinacoes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Vacina> Vacinas { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controler

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? Idvacina)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }    
        var viewModel = new VacinacaoIndexData();    
        viewModel.Vacinacoes = db.Vacinacao
            .Include(v => v.Vacinas)
            .Include(v => v.Crianca)
            .Where(c => c.IdCentro == user.IdCentro);  

        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.IdVacinacao = id.Value;
            viewModel.Vacinas = viewModel.Vacinacoes
                .Single(i => i.IdVacinacao == id.Value).Vacinas;
        }    
        if (Idvacina == null) return View(viewModel);           
            ViewBag.IdVacina = Idvacina.Value;
            // Lazy loading
            viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Vacinas.Single(x => x.IdVacina == Idvacina).Enrollments;
        // Explicit loading
        Vacina selectedVacina = viewModel.Vacinas.Single(x => x.IdVacina == Idvacina);    
        db.Entry(selectedVacina).Collection(x => x.Enrollments).Load();

            foreach (var enrollment in selectedVacina.Enrollments)
            {
                db.Entry(enrollment).Reference(x => x.Centro).Load();
            }    
            viewModel.Enrollments = selectedVacina.Enrollments;            

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

In the Field Name I would like to Show Child Name, but it does not return anything

```
      @model GestCentros.ViewModels.VacinacaoIndexData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2 class="text-center">Lista de Crianças Vacinadas</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Data Vacinação</th>
        <th>Vacinas</th>
        <th>Operações</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Vacinacoes)
     {
        string selectedRow = "";
        if (item.IdVacinacao == ViewBag.IdVacinacao)
        {
            selectedRow = "success";
        }
        <tr class="@selectedRow">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Crianca.Nome)

            </td>
            <td>
                @item.DataVacina.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            </td>
            <td>
                @{
                    foreach (var vacina in item.Vacinas)
                    {
                        @:  @vacina.Nome <br />
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
</table>

@if (Model.Vacinas != null)
{
    <h3>Vacinas Ministradas na Campanha</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Operações</th>
            <th>Vacina</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Vacinas)
        {
            var selectedRow = "";
            if (item.IdVacina == ViewBag.IdVacina)
            {
                selectedRow = "success";
            }
            <tr class="@selectedRow">
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Selecionar", "Index", new { IdVacina = item.IdVacina }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-secundary" })
                    | @Html.ActionLink("Voltar a Lista", "Index", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-default" })
                </td>                
                <td>
                    @item.Nome
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}

@if (Model.Enrollments != null)
{
    <h3>
        Students Enrolled in Selected Course
    </h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Centro.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: I get this error:

The object reference was not defined as an instance of an object. '

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean

Comment: Where in the code are you getting the error?

Comment: when I do the execution. (when I call the index page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I would like Codigo to help me, because I have already read about all this and I can not see the error.
so if you can take a look at the codido, thank you