# "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" in Unity 2019.2.4f1

Tags: c#

Unity is throwing out this compiler error when I run my code

> "Assets\Stealth.cs(25,13): error CS0120: An object reference is
>   required for the non-static field, method, or property
>   'RaycastHit2D.collider'"

I've tried declaring the RaycastHit2D variable in multiple different ways, and all throw out a different error.

```
public float rotationSpeed;
public float distance;

private void Start()
{
    Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
}


void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(RaycastHit2D.collider.CompareTag("Player")){
        Destroy(RaycastHit2D.collider.gameObject);
    }
    RaycastHit2D RaycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, distance);
    if (RaycastHit2D.collider != null){
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, RaycastHit2D.point, Color.red);
    } else {
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.right * distance, Color.green);
    }
}
```

}

It should cause a gameObject I have in the scene to destroy the player when the ray comes in contact with the player's 2D collider, and this isn't happening.

Comment: `RaycastHit2D` is the class, not an object. The class itself does not have a collider. Only the object the class generates holds a collider.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Amy it says right in the second paragraph of the post what line is throwing the error. The line where he is accessing `'RaycastHit2D.collider`. Both of the calls to this should be throwing the same error.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu Thanks, I misread that part of the error message somehow.

Comment: See also https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-collider.html for correct usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler error CS0120 is saying that you are trying to access an instance member as though it were a static member.

`RaycastHit2D` is a class name, so the expression `RaycastHit2D.collider` is trying to access a static member named `collider`. However, `collider` is an instance property, so you need an *instance* of `RaycastHit2D` instead.

Your variable `RaycastHit` holds an instance of this class, so you may have intended to write `RaycastHit.collider` instead, like this:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    RaycastHit2D RaycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, distance);
    if (RaycastHit.collider != null){

        // This had to be moved below where RaycastHit is assigned,
        // and after verifying that collider is not null
        if(RaycastHit.collider.CompareTag("Player")){
            Destroy(RaycastHit.collider.gameObject);
        }

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, RaycastHit.point, Color.red);
    } else {
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.right * distance, Color.green);
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the compiler error, but now I have the error "object reference not set to the instance of an object", what does this mean? Thank you.

Comment: @HARRISONYOUNGMAN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean