# Cannot click on Data Source in Properties to select new Object data sourc created

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, data-binding, datasource, error-messaging

Visual Studio - C#
The problem lies when I click on the Data Source dropdown menu in Properties - bindingSource; it throws an error message.

Error message pop-up: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[image]

[image]

When I create the Object Data Source, it doesn't appear in the DataSources folder in solution explorer either.

[image: No new data source file appears in the DataSources folder]

I'm relatively new to coding; everything seems fine, so I am trying to understand why it will not work. I was expecting it to work, and it would auto-generate a data source file. Please help.

Edit: Solution/Project isn't on test when error message fires and it doesn't throw an exception or show an error in Error List for the entire solution.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR6bW.png Your problem doesn't appear when I pull down, your picture is blurry and it's hard for me to discern the information. See [bingsource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/bindingsource-component?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) how to use the component. This is how to add data source [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-data-sources?view=vs-2022) .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/779091/16764901 In my case, I cannot reproduce your error. Please let me know if you solve the problem from my information. I'll edit this as an answer.

Comment: Just a wild guess. What type of project is this? Does it target .NET Framework, or .NET 5 (or above?) The Data Source window is only supported for .NET Framework projects. Could it be you tried to change the target platform at some point?